# PHP function not working prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi there I'm using a function to check user messages but right now I am unable to get it work.

> error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a
>   non-object

```
public function HasMessageReadData($id)
{
    $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("use ".$GLOBALS['db_ucp']."");
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message_read WHERE msg = ? AND id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $message = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if($message[0] > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `$result` isn't instantiated anywhere.

Comment: @Darren Yes, and this question is therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: @lonesomeday I didn't mark as a duplicate or anything....

Comment: @Darren Indeed. I'm agreeing with you. Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: @lonesomeday Oh! I see! Sorry I'm a bit lost after work! Thanks :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you haven't instantiated `$result` anywhere, yet you try to call it via:

```
$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Which results in your error. You'd probably want to use something like:

`$stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);`

**Optionally you could do something like this**

```
public function HasMessageReadData($id)
{
    $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("use ".$GLOBALS['db_ucp']."");
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message_read WHERE msg = ? AND id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $this->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $message = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if($message[0] > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Reading: [**Dynamically bind param array mysqli...**](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)